# CML (Chronic Myeloid Leukemia) and blast cell percentage

Tags: cancer, hematology, cell-culture, stem-cells

I'm trying to understand the oncogenesis of CML. I have a question about CFC cells and blast cells. Are those the same? I know that in the chronic phase of CML there is a blast percentage of 1-10% of blast cells in the blood. Considering that the total amount of WBC is around 1x10<sup>–11</sup> cells/l. That means the blast cells should be around the same order of magnitude. Looking on research articles I found that the amount of CFC (which contains according to my understanding all of the blast cells) are only 1x10<sup>–8</sup> cells/l. Thus comprising around 0.1% of the blood count.

What cells can be considered as blasts? Only the myeloblasts? Are all blast cells CFC cells?
I also know that the average value of CFC cells in the bone marrow is around 10<sup>–5</sup> cells, so how can they be 10<sup>–9</sup> cells?

Reference:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9922073/

Comment: Not to be rude, but are you *sure* you read the article?  Figure 1 describes the CFU ontology and defines CFC as experimentally-determined CFUs.  Table 2 describes the relative number of each CFU per 10$^5$ marrow cells.  Those numbers are much closer to your 0.1% figure than the 1-10% value expected during chronic-phase CML.  Re: your final question, leukemia is pretty much defined by immature cells leaving the marrow, which would elevate the PB levels.  Ta-da!

Comment: I did read the article, but I'm learning about leukemia to make inter-disciplinary research, it's not my field of expertise. I am pretty confused about the percentages. If the CFC build up <1% of the cells in the bone marrow and immature blast cells are contained within the CFC compartment, how can they be present at 10% in PB? The only possible solution for me is: The 10% blast cells compromises not only the CFC but other types of cells. Which other types of cells? It seems that every article assumes a definition of blast cells I just don't find anywhere. Thank you for your help.